# Filter out the word

Tags: r

I want to Filter out the common words in rm_words from critic_smart, and create a bar chart to display the top 20 most common words.
Here is my code:

```
rm_words <- c("animal", "crossing", "horizons", "game", "nintendo", 
              "switch", "series", "island")
p1 <- critic_smart %>%
  filter((str_detect(word, rm_words))) %>%
  count(word) %>%
  slice_max(n, n = 20) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = n, y = fct_reorder(word, n))) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(x = "Frequency of words", y = "")
p1
```

The code only count the word in rm_word but in fact, I want to remover these word in rm_words, what can i do to filter out it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example. It is not possible for us to know what `critic_smart` is. As it looks, you could maybe try `!str_detect(word, rm_words)` instead of `str_detect(word, rm_words)`.

Comment: I have tried the !str_detect(word, rm_words) it did not work and the word does not filter out by this function

Comment: Ok, so please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

If the words in `critic_smart` will only be exact matches to the words in `rm_words`, then you can just test for inclusion in the vector, `filter(!(word %in% rm_words))`.

If the words in `critic_smart$word` might contain a substring equal to something in `rm_words` and you want to remove it in that scenario, you can make a regex pattern out of the `rm_words` vector to be used with `grepl` or `str_detect`.

`filter(!grepl(paste(rm_words , collapse = "|"), word))`